# Apollo GraphQL: Child Component Re-Runs Parent Query?

Tags: apollostack, apollo-server, react-apollo

I've got a parent component with an Apollo query attached:

```
const withData = graphql(MY_QUERY, {
    options({ userID }) {
        return {
            variables: { _id: userID}
        };
    },
    props({ data: { loading, getOneUser } }) {
        return { loading, getOneUser };
    },
});

export default compose(
    withData,
    withApollo
)(NavigatorsList);

export { getOneUser_QUERY };
```

I've got a child component called `userPhoto` embedded in the render function:

```
   return (
        <div>
            <userPhoto />
            [.....]
        </div>
        )
```

Without the child component, the withData GraphQL function runs twice, once for `loading == true`, and one more time with the data returned.

With the child component included, the withData GraphQL function runs **three times**. The third time `getOneUser` is undefined and my component throws an error.

How can I correct this?

Thanks in advance to all for any info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. There was a syntax error in the child component that wasn't throwing an error, but was causing the query to run twice + assorted other anomalies.